# How can I route to localhost:2233/username?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

In mvc 4 I am trying to route to something like this `http://localhost:22128/username`. In my `route.config`

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

For this do I need to change `url` format? how can I route ? Can someone help me to solve this? I am very confused on this.

### Edit

I tried this

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        "UserProfile",
        "{username}",
        new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", username = string.Empty }
        );
```

but Still it not finding the profile controller in index method.

Comment: You need to place the specific "UserProfile" route before the "Default" route.

Comment: Yeah I tried but I want to call this only when there is `localhost:2243/username` otherwise it should call Home/Index. Right now it is calling Profile/Index.

Answer (score 1):

Routes are *order specific*. They are tried from the first route registered to the last.

Since the default route matches every URL with 0, 1, 2, or 3 segments no URL defined after it with any of those lengths will work.

So you need to define your `UserProfile` route before the `Default` route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UserProfile",
    "{username}",
    new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", username = string.Empty }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```